# Xamarin - Android - Splash Screen (Multiple)

Tags: android, xamarin, splash-screen

I just started using xamarin to create my first android app and i'm having a small issue .

I wanted to have 2 splash screen at the beginning of the app.

I created a first one which works fine , then a second one then the mainActivity.

For some reason however , it doesn't shows the second splash screen.

if i remove this line in the second one , then it works but doesn't go to the mainActivity then.

```
StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash1", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Thread.Sleep(3000); 

            StartActivity(typeof(SplashActivity2));
        }
    };

    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash2", NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity2 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Thread.Sleep(3000); 

            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        }
    };

    [Activity (Label = "coco1_droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because you're sleeping the UI thread with `Thread.Sleep(3000)` the UI freezes and the new Activity is started before the `OnCreate` method returns.

I recommend using a Timer (ex: `System.Timers.Timer`) to wait the three seconds before starting the new activity. That way the UI does not freeze and the `OnCreate` method returns.

I've modified your example with my suggestion:

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash1", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 3000; // 3 sec.
            timer.AutoReset = false; // Do not reset the timer after it's elapsed
            timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(SplashActivity2));
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
    };

    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash2", NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity2 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 3000; // 3 sec.
            timer.AutoReset = false; // Do not reset the timer after it's elapsed
            timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
    };

    [Activity (Label = "coco1_droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks for sharing mate. @Jimmy - +1 this answer and mark it as the answer.